# What's the current opinion on encouraging footnotes in answers?

Tags: discussion

I have just edited out

> [Keep coding................ :)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17654256/revisions)

from the answer. It made me think, because I sometimes saw and used sentences encouraging the newbies, like

> This is a hard topic, but it will be rewarding if you put enough effort into it.

Now, I think the former is just introducing noise, and the latter can perhaps add some reasoning to the suggestions, especially for beginners.

I'd like to ask the community if such lines are encouraged or not, and if yes, how far to the casual "keep coding" we can go?

Comment: I posted a response to a similar question on the UX Meta site - http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/a/1401/3865

Comment: @JonW great example indeed, thanks! `:)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple - does it add value to the answer?

No? - edit out.

Yes? - keep it in.

---

In my opinion, something like this should be in a comment.

Comment: If I saw a comment that said `Keep coding................ :)` I would flag it.

Comment: @CodyGray then it's even clearer than it shouldn't be there, no?